# How to deploy mysql datasource using jboss-as-maven-plugin

Tags: mysql, maven, jboss, jboss7.x

This question is here to give an answer to once i find a solution, I have found documentation on Postgresql and H2 databases from the jboss [website](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/add-resource-example.html) and have seen how it is done manually through this [website](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7), however I cannot seem to find much information on how to deploy a mysql datasource using the jboss-as-maven-plugin.

What is the minimum configuration properties required to properly register a mysql datasource with jboss-as 7 server through their maven plugin?

I have this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And this configuration for the maven plugin

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <execute-commands/>
                <executeCommands/>
                <properties>
                    <enable-welcome-root>false</enable-welcome-root>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                ...
                <!-- deploy the mysql connectorj -->
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-mysql-driver</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <name>mysql.jar</name>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-datasource</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <address>subsystem=datasources</address>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <address>xa-data-source=java:global/datasources/tncDS</address>
                                <enable-resource>true</enable-resource>
                                <properties>
                                    <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/tncDS</jndi-name>
                                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tnc</connection-url>
                                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                                    <driver-name>mysql.jar</driver-name>
                                </properties>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            ...
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

running the command `mvn jboss-as:run` causes this error:

```xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.241s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 24 21:37:28 EST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/308M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:deploy-artifact (deploy-mysql-driver) on project ear: Could not execute goal deploy-artifact on null. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**UPDATE:**

I have developed a plugin that injects the required file (`META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`) into the jar before deployment:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.thenaglecode</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-jdbc-compliance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.26</version>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>modify-connector</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However i'm still getting `could not connect to remote` message. Is there a step that i'm missing or doing in the wrong sequence as i understand that the run command should start up the server.

**UPDATE 2:**
After some fiddling and reading of the jboss-as plugin [website](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/complex-example.html), I realized that the `jboss-as:run` goal also invokes the `package` phase. I was mostly receiving this error when I tried to run any of the deploying goals bound to the `package` phase.

**Anything that needs to be deployed should be bound to the `install` phase.**

I am now getting a seperate error regarding my persistence unit not existing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the MySQL driver is not JDBC 4 compliant. You need to add a `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file to the JAR with the fully qualified JDBC driver class name *or* install it as a module. See https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7 for more details.

Comment: Is there a way to do this through maven or must i write my own plugin to ad the file to the jar?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I'd have to look at how to do it. Maybe in the jar:jar plugin/goal.

Comment: I've developed a plugin to do this now, but i'm still facing the same issues. the only way I've resolved the `Could not connect to remote` message was to start a seperate instance of the server manually. but i want my tent to fold out automatically :P

Comment: Try passing `-Djboss-as.hostname=127.0.0.1`. Maybe localhost isn't defined.

Comment: in the java runtime arguments? or somewhere in the maven plugin?

Comment: Either. You can pass it like `mvn jboss-as:run -Djboss-as.hostname=127.0.0.1` or add `<hostname>127.0.0.1</homename>` to the config in your pom.

Answer (score 0):

solution here:

conf : jboss as7, maven 3.3.3, mysql java connector 5.1.29 28 27 26...,

starting from mysql java connector 5.1.30, the file Meta-INF/serivces/java.sql.driver contain this line "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver", if I change it to "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" the datasource is created and the project deployed fine.

with mysql java connector 5.1.29 28 27 26 ..., that file contain only "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", the deployement work fine.

check my pom.xml here 
https://github.com/anouarattn/GestionAbsence